# Making StatET work with R 2.15.0

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

I seem to have an impedance mismatch between Eclipse, R, RJ and StatET.
I am using:

- A vanilla Eclipse 3.7 classic (Indigo)
- R 2.15.0

both on a Windows 7, 32 bit machine
and I want to use StatET.
In order to do this I installed:

- RJ 1.0.3-7 (but for R 2.14.0)
- RJ.gd 1.0.3-3 (but for R 2.14.0)
- StatET 2.0

StatET does not seem to have an RJ release for R-2.15.0 yet, so I used the one for R-2.14, but it does not work for me. 
I get an error ("R ddl version does not match: DLL: 2.15.0 JRI:2.14.1")
Should I downgrade my R version, or is there a newer StatET + RJ version I am unaware of?

Comment: I couldn't find a newer version of RJ. You can keep the newer version of R on your machine and set up Eclipse to launch the older console - in Console Run Configurations, that way you can switch when the RJ version is (hopefully) updated - without too much trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The testing version of StatET 3.0 with RJ 1.1 currently works with R 2.15.

Binaries of RJ 1.1 were recently made available and can be installed with:

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")
```

Alternatively, binaries or source code of RJ can be downloaded from:

http://www.walware.de/it/downloads/rj.mframe

The update site for StatET 3.0 is:

http://download.walware.de/eclipse-3.7/testing

or

http://download.walware.de/eclipse-3.6/testing

depending on your version of Eclipse. More details on StatET 3.0 are available in these two threads:

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2012-May/001408.html

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2012-February/001284.html